# How to generate a downloadable CSV file from a View table?

Tags: 7, views, importing-exporting

Is there any way to generate a downloadable CSV file from a View table?
If not, how can I generate a CSV file in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create/export CSV files from Views in Drupal 7 with the [Views Data Export](http://drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module.  The module is currently in Beta.